# OR query with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with "name" and "description" filed. I am running a Boolean query against my index. Sometimes the term is present in both name and description fields, in this case the documents in which both the name and description contains the search term are scored higher compared to the ones having either the name or the description having the search term.

What I want is to score them equal. So the the documents with either name or description having the term has the same score as the document having the search term present in both name and description.

Is it possible?

Here is the example:

```
{
    "name":     "xyz",
    "description":  "abc xyz"
},
{
    "name":     "abc",
    "description":  "xyz pqr"
},
{
    "name":     "xyz",
    "description":  "abc pqr"
}
```

If the user search for term "xyz" I want all three documents above to have the same score.
As all documents contains the term "xyz" either in name or in description or in both fields.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Filtered Query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) for this. Filters are not scored. See the query below for searching the term `"xyz"`:

```
POST <index name>/<type>/_search
{
    "filtered": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "should": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "name": "xyz"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "description": "xyz"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either :

- transform you query to a filter. Filters do not affect score (and are faster than queries)
- or wrap your query in a "Constant score query" - see : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/constant-score-query/